# Android : when to unregister the listener - onStop() or onDestroy()

Tags: android

I have basic question regarding when to `unregisterListener` for sensor manager. Should it be done in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`.

Usecase :

I want to record `accelorometer` on click of start button and stop when user clicks stop button. the frequency of data is every minute. So I have started a `timer`.

But the issue is every time the `orientation` changes as per Android architecture, `onStop()` gets called. In `onStop()` I am cancelling the timer and unregistering the listener.

SO again if I start timer/register listener in `onResume()` the frequency won't remain 1 minute and also the data gets recorded without user pressing the start button.

Can someone help me resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnDestroy()` isn't guaranteed to be called. So you should do it in either `onPause` or `onStop`

> But the issue is every time the orientation changes as per Android architecture

There's a way to prevent this from happening in the manifest. I'm sure someone else will post how.

Comment: I understand the Android documentation for `onDestroy` to mean that you should not *save* data there, as the process may be killed before it is called. However in that situation, so will any listeners registered to the sensor manager. What's the harm in this?

Comment: Also of note, `onStop` is also not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: onPause is the only one guaranteed. I have seen instances where onStop is not called, so when navigating back to the app a new fragment instance will have is onStart called, and a listener is leaked (unless you register listeners using string tags, and the new fragment replaces the old listener)

Comment: If you're supporting pre-HoneyComb devices, then you should _always_ use `onPause`. If you're only supporting post-HoneyComb devices, then it is safe to use `onStop`. Source: [Reto Meier](https://plus.google.com/+RetoMeier)

Comment: Reto mentions to always use onPause here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=631T7B8HOv4

Comment: "OnDestroy() isn't guaranteed to be called" - official docs with confirmation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use a `Service` to run the accelerometer data collecting in the background, communicating with it using basic intents is not too complicated.

Or, if you only want to 'survive' the rotation, when the activity gets destoryed and then rebuilt, try overriding in your `Activity` the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` methods (read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29))

Comment: I solved it using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and getLastNonConfigurationInstance() methods .. thanks